# Table has no column in google charts and php

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

i need help with my google chart...i currently have a getdata.php which has a query with information from my DB table..i have a page that enables one to select a particular user, once the user is selected i use the &_GET option to get an ID and feed it into the query in getData.php so that its dynamic with chart generation, the end product/chart is not being displyed as i have a no column message.. here is my getData.php and chart1.php which displays chart.

**chart1.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.


google.load('visualization', '1', {
'packages' : [ 'corechart' ]


 });

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.

 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var jsonData = $.ajax({
  url : "getData.php?",
  type: "GET" , // or GET, depends on your choice data

  dataType : "json",
  async : false

}).responseText;

   // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document
    .getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data);
}
```

**getData.php**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
        $getid = $_GET['id'];

        $graphquery =" SELECT sa.userid
              ,q.question_group_id
              ,sum(pa.answer)/(select count(q.question)*3)*100 as 'Percentage'
        FROM surveyanswers sa
        INNER JOIN possibleanswers pa
        ON pa.possible_answer_id = sa.answer_voted
        INNER JOIN questions q
        ON q.question_id = sa.question_id
        WHERE userid='$getid'
        GROUP BY question_group_id";
        $result_set=mysql_query($graphquery, $connection);

        echo '{
          "cols": [
                {"id":"","label":"Groupname","pattern":"","type":"string"},
                {"id":"","label":"Percentage","pattern":"","type":"number"}
                ],
          "rows": [';
           while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)){

               echo '{"c":[{"v":"'.$row['question_group_id'].'"},{"v":'.$row['Percentage'].'}]},';
           }

           echo ' ]
        }';

}
```

Comment: If you run the select statement by itself do you get any results?

Comment: This jsFiddle works with static data, so there must be something wrong with the DB query or the ajax call: https://jsfiddle.net/phcbo1vr/4/

Comment: yes  @TheGunner , issue is on the inner join query when i give a random user id that is on the database the chart generates...my issue is that i dont want to have fixed values on the query thats why i am using the $_GET[id] ...Definately my json is not gwtting the query result but i dont know what i have done wrong

Comment: @dstudeba , if i run the select statement with a fixed user id value thats on the DB i get the chart generation, but with the '$getid' theres nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the issue was with how i pass data..i added an extra field called data and passed my php get id through it on chart1.php ...on the getdata.php i called the $_GET[id] and its now generating the charts dynamically..Spent so much time but i guess its a learning curve.

**chart1.php**

```
 function drawChart() {
var jsonData = $.ajax({
  url : "getData.php",
  type: "GET" , // or GET, depends on your choice data
  data:"id=<?php echo "$_GET[id]";?>", 
  dataType : "json",
  async : false

}).responseText;
```

**getdata.php**

```
        $graphquery =" SELECT q.question_group_id
   , qg.group_name
   ,sum(pa.answer)/(select
   count(q.question)*3)*100 as 'Percentage' 
  FROM surveyanswers sa


INNER JOIN possibleanswers pa
on  pa.possible_answer_id = sa.answer_voted



INNER JOIN questions q
on q.question_id = sa.question_id
and userid=$_GET[id]

INNER JOIN questionsgroup qg
on qg.question_group_id= q.question_group_id
 group by question_group_id;";



       $result_set=mysql_query($graphquery, $connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your SELECT string is set up incorrectly.  Try this:

```
$graphquery ="SELECT sa.userid
          ,q.question_group_id
          ,sum(pa.answer)/(select count(q.question)*3)*100 as 'Percentage'
    FROM surveyanswers sa
    INNER JOIN possibleanswers pa
    ON pa.possible_answer_id = sa.answer_voted
    INNER JOIN questions q
    ON q.question_id = sa.question_id
    WHERE userid=" . $getid . " GROUP BY question_group_id";
```

You can also print out the `$graphquery` variable before running the SQL statement to check it.

Comment: i have implemented that..looks more correct because of the concartenation..now the issue is with the passing of the json ID..if that works then i beleive with this query i should get my charts

Comment: Rather  the issue now is with the passing of the ID via the url in ajax..if that works then i beleive with this query i should get my charts

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't passing an `id` variable via your url in your ajax call.

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
  url : "getData.php?id="+userid,
  type: "GET" , // or GET, depends on your choice data

  dataType : "json",
  async : false

}).responseText;
```

The result is that the `$getid` variable is never populated, rendering your SQL query invalid. Obviously, you'll have to make sure that the `userid` variable gets populated somehow.

Comment: i have done so though am getting an error of "userid not defined"..though i have noticed my mistake which you pointed out, the ID  has to be passed via url in ajax..any other suggestion on passing the URL? i have tried "getData.php?id="$_GET[id], and gotten an error as well

Comment: So, I put `userid` in as a basic placeholder, you have to define that somewhere based on a known value. Based on what I'm seeing, you'll likely define that in your chart1.php. Put something like `var userid='<?= $known_user_id ?>'` right before your `var jsonData...` line. What you tried will only work if chart1.php is also called with a `$_GET` variable of `id` as well, like `chart1.php?id=12345`.

Comment: thats true @TheGunner , the known value wasnt getting picked because it was inside a javascript and $_GET works inside php tags..so i added the php tags inside the javascript..Thanks so much for your help,you have really helped me to get where i have..cheers mate!